# Treating an array as if it was a circle

Tags: arrays

I have a program I'm writing to play a song and display an image. Currently, images are stored on the file system and loaded into memory just before sliding them onto the screen from left or right. This takes time and causes delay in the UI as the images are quite large. I can only store a few images in the limited video memory on the device. What I would like to do is have an array, into which images that are further than a few steps away from display on screen are unloaded from memory. However, I want to treat the Array as a circle - when you hit zero, you go to the other end of the array instead of stopping.

```
[unloaded,unloaded,image,image,image (on screen),image,image image,unloaded,unloaded]
```

if I was in the middle of the array as above, I could always remove the -3 and +3 elements. How would the logic work to handle treating it as a loop? I'm having trouble conceiving of an elegant if/then structure to handle this. If it was not being treated as a loop, the code would look something like this if moving to the right:

```
if msg=event.right_button_pressed then
    currentindex=currentindex+1
    lowindex=currentindex-3
    highindex=currentindex+3
    array[lowindex]=invalid
    array[highindex]=loadimagefromdisk()
    screen.drawobject(array[currentindex])
end if
```

Can someone suggest simple way to handle wrapping the loading and unloading pointers to the ends of the array when they are beyond the scope of the array?

currentindex is wrapped by:

```
if currentindex > array.count() -1 then currentindex=0
if currentindex < 0 then currentindex=array.count() - 1
```

Comment: I would use two stacks (one for previous, one for next), because I'm lazy - it simplifies the problem conceptually and, with just a few operations defined can coordinate everything trivially: take next -> prev, read to next if required, put current -> prev, etc.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by stacks, perhaps as part of answering the question? Do you mean two arrays? or do you mean some kind of LIFO structure?

Comment: Possible for you to use a linked list?

Comment: @alphablender A FIFO with the ability to work from both ends, I suppose. In JavaScript, Arrays are suitable for this.

Comment: @kyle I would like to use if possible one array and either compute the correct pointers using math or logic or both. This is a BASIC-like language that has two data structure types: Array and AssociativeArray (data dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to inspiration from the commentors, here is my solution: Run all three index pointers through the same wrap-around function:

```
playindex = wrap(playindex,playlist.count() - 1)
highindex = wrap(highindex,playlist.count() - 1)
lowindex = wrap(lowindex,playlist.count() - 1)

function wrap(p as integer, count as integer) as integer
    if p > count then p = 0
    if p < 0 then p = count
    return p
end function
```